# Python read IMU data from Arduino and print

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have Arduino code (actually Teensy 3.2) sending data over serial

```
void loop()
{
  data1 = roll; // integer
  data2 = pitch; // integer 
  data3 = yaw; // integer

  byte buf1[4];
  buf1[0] = data1 & 255;
  buf1[1] = (data1 >> 8)  & 255;
  buf1[2] = (data1 >> 16) & 255;
  buf1[3] = (data1 >> 24) & 255;
  Serial.write(buf1, sizeof(buf1));

  byte buf2[4];
  buf2[0] = data2 & 255;
  buf2[1] = (data2 >> 8)  & 255;
  buf2[2] = (data2 >> 16) & 255;
  buf2[3] = (data2 >> 24) & 255;
  Serial.write(buf2, sizeof(buf2));

  byte buf3[4];
  buf3[0] = data3 & 255;
  buf3[1] = (data3 >> 8)  & 255;
  buf3[2] = (data3 >> 16) & 255;
  buf3[3] = (data3 >> 24) & 255;
  Serial.write(buf3, sizeof(buf3));

  while (micros() - loop_timer < 2500);
  loop_timer = micros();
}
```

And I want to receive the data and print it in python:

```
import serial
import time
import csv
import sys

PORT = '/dev/tty.usbserial-AL03QWTA'
BAUD = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD)

while True:
    data1 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data2 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data3 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data4 = ord(ser.read(1));
    roll = (data4*256*256*256 + data3*256*256 + data2*256 + data1);
    data5 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data6 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data7 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data8 = ord(ser.read(1));
    pitch = (data8*256*256*256 + data7*256*256 + data6*256 + data5);
    data9 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data10 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data11 = ord(ser.read(1));
    data12 = ord(ser.read(1));
    yaw = (data12*256*256*256 + data11*256*256 + data10*256 + data9);
    print(roll + "," + pitch + "," + yaw)
```

It seems the received data are mixed up and are not received properly. What is the best way to send the data (roll, pitch, and yaw) from Arduino to python knowing that the Arduino updates the data every 0.0025s.

Comment: Note that Arduino's `micros()` function returns an integer number of microseconds - your `micros() - loop_timer < 0.0025` condition doesn't do what you seem to think it does, the only reason this creates a delay at all is that floating-point math is *slow*.

Comment: Correction. It should be 2500 instead of 0.0025.